# custom title all over the pages on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want a specific title (`<title>My Title!</title>`) all over the pages of my website. If I just edit the header.php with `<title>My Title!</title>` it doesn't work and display the default title of the Wordpress. how can I change it? I know there is a function wp_title() but I dont think it helps.

Thank you.

Comment: Post your header template (the important part) to us, so we could help a little more

Answer (score 0):

You just need to edit header.php. Are you sure youre editing the correct header.php file?

If you edit it under Appearance->editor->header.php in your admin youll be sure to be editing the correct one.

Comment: I edited fine. If I remove the <title> there isn't title, but if I write a custom title there is the default title of Wordpress (web site name | page name)

Answer (score 0):

Look for wp_head in the header.php file...
Removing the wp_head might cause you some other problems like a plugin not functioning well or so. Be careful with that, and i dont understand why u want to have the same title all over your site.

Answer (score 0):

Include this to the header.php(after  tag):

```
<title><?php if(is_home()) { echo bloginfo('name');  echo " - "; echo "Home";} else { 
echo wp_title(" - ", false, right); echo bloginfo(‘name’); } ?></title>
```